# How to incorporate negative controls in DESeq2

Tags: rna-seq, differential-expression, deseq2

We are doing a comparison between two outcomes (positive and negative). We could not have any positive controls as we do not have any "control" data to set as baseline, either from literature or otherwise. No spike-ins have been used. We have some samples which had no resolved outcome, hence we are skeptic of using those as Controls.

We have few negative control samples which contain just the blank culture media with no RNA. We want to remove these signals from the RNA-seq data, but I would like to know the most ideal way to perform this. I would assume just normalizing and subtracting counts wouldn't be the most ideal.

So here's what the `coldata` looks like -

```
Sample_ID   Outcome
S1  Positive
S2  Negative
S3  Unknown
S4  Negative
…   …
```

My previous post has been about the [same experiment](https://support.bioconductor.org/p/9154760/)

Here are the counts for the top 5 genes with high counts in negative samples (RIF1, GOLGB1, C10orf67, MAP3K15, F8):

```
Geneid  S1  S2  S3  S4  S5  S6  S7  S8  S9  S10 S11 S12 S13 S14 S15 S16 S17 S18 S19 S20 S21
ENSG00000189283.11  2284    2986    4577    2447    1290    1882    1953    1366    2443    3932    2640    1078    491 2919    1248    1627    1805    2094    2229    2789    190
ENSG00000173230.17  1000    1219    1324    1485    722 1142    870 943 1390    1617    1093    564 86  924 778 1059    1144    1248    1169    1828    50
ENSG00000180815.15  641 723 1118    1758    529 865 683 878 1554    2421    1571    414 136 1076    599 924 1098    1199    1405    1327    54
ENSG00000179133.15  369 433 592 488 305 366 335 252 455 2119    1357    118 159 314 200 284 376 333 517 550 17
ENSG00000256637.9   429 491 523 550 250 410 406 359 552 438 339 176 38  357 296 433 517 514 631 779 24
```

Comment: We plan to subtract the median count for these genes from the count matrix of all samples. If the value dips to negative, they will be replaced by 0. Is there a better way to handle background from negative controls? After all these signals are present in all samples, so I'm inclined to believe these signals are noise from the media itself, rather than anything biologically significant from the cells.